# Throw Custom Exception From ANTLR4 Grammar File

Tags: antlr, grammar

I have a grammar file which parse a specific file type. Now I need a simple thing.
I have a parser rule, and when the parser rule doesn't satisfy with the input token I need to throw my own custom exception.
That is, when my input file is giving me an extraneous error because the parser is expecting something and the i/p file doesn't has that. I want to throw an exception in this scenario.
Is this possible ?
If yes, How ?
If no, any work around ?

I'm beginner in this skill.

```
grammar Test

exampleParserRule : [a-z]+ ;
```

My input file contains 12345. Now I need to throw a custom exception

Comment: Catch the ANTLR exceptions and learn what's wrong first, https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RecognitionException.html Then you can create and throw your own exceptions.

Comment: I could able to read the message as extraneous input error because of the unexpected content in the file(The rule can accept only [a-z]). So, here, instead of dealing with the default exception I need to throw a custom one, so I can catch it in the calling method to do the needful in this specific case. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For parsing issues such as this, ANTLR will, internally, throw certain exceptions, but they are caught and handled by an ErrorListener.  By default, ANTLR will hook up a ConsoleErrorListener that just formats and writes error messages to the console.  But it will then continue processing, attempting to recover from the error, and sync back up with your input.  This is something you want in a parser.  It’s not very useful to have a parser just report the first problem it encounters and then exception out.

You can implement your own ErrorListener (there’s a BaseErrorListener class you can subclass).  There you can handle the reported error yourself (the method you override provide a lot of detailed information about the error) and produce whatever message you’d like.  (You can also do things like collect all the errors in a list, keep track of error levels, etc.)

In short, you probably don’t want a different exception, you want a different error message.

Sometimes, depending on how difficult it is to sort out your particular situation for a custom message, it’s really better to look for it in a Listener that processes the parse tree that ANTLR hands back.  (Note: a very common path beginners take is to try to get *everything* into the grammar.  It’s going to be hard to get really nice error messages if you do this.  ANTLR is pretty good with error messages, but, as a generalized tool, it’s just more likely you can produce more meaningful messages.)

Just try to get ANTLR to produce a parse tree that accurately reflects the structure of your input.  Then you can walk the ParseTree with a validation Listener of your own code, producing your own messages.

Another “trick” that doesn’t occur to many ANTLR devs (early on), is that the grammar doesn’t HAVE to ONLY include rules for valid input.  If there’s some particular input you want to give a more helpful error message for, you can add a rule to match that (invalid) input, and when you encounter that Context in your validation listener, generate an error message specific to that construct.

BTW… `[a-z]+` would almost always be a Lexer rule. If you don’t yet understand the difference between lexer and parser rules, or the processing pipeline ANTLR uses to tokenize an input stream, and then parse a token stream, do yourself a favor and get a firm understanding of those basics.  ANTLR is going to be very confusing without that basic understanding.  It’s pretty simple, but very important to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your grammar:

```
grammar Test

@header {
package $your.$package;

import $your.$package.$yourExceptionClass;
}


exampleParserRule : [a-z]+ ;
catch [RecognitionException re] {
    reportError(re);
    recover(input,re);
    retval.tree = (CommonTree)adaptor.errorNode(input, retval.start, input.LT(-1), re);
    String msg = getErrorMessage(re, this.getTokenNames());
    throw new $yourExceptionClass(msg, re);
}
```

It's up to you if you really want to `reportError`(logs to console) , `recover` etc. - but these are the defaults so it may be good to use these.
Also, you may want to generate a more human readable error message (use `getErrorMessage`.

If you do more complex work follow @mike-cargal`s advice.